# Is there a way to require a USB thumbdrive token for my Windows 7 login?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I'm looking for something--hopefully a group policy--that allows me to use a usb flash/thumbdrive as my login, or as the second factor along with my password.

In a nutshell, I'm doing this because I want to limit my own access to the administrator accounts on my laptop during the day, so that I'm jailed to an account that only has access to MS Word and some work-related websites.

If it's avoidable, I would prefer not to use third-party software.

Comment: The only native support that I am aware of for windows, as far as access is concerned is [this](http://thecustomizewindows.com/2010/12/create-an-usb-key-to-lock-and-unlock-windows-7/) however there are plenty of third party apps that do what you want, I am not sure about group policy though.

Answer (score 1):

A GoldKey will secure a Windows 7 account right out of the box.

You can even install Active Directory certificates in it so you can use special Group Policies per key.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some third party software.  Unfortunately, USB drives aren't encrypted nor secure and thus give little reason for Microsoft to implement them as a multi factor authentication.

In most secure environments I've seen, USB ports are just straight up disabled in BIOS or disconnected physically.